# How to read the excel file from java code which is external to the system?

Tags: java, external, file-read

I'm using java (eclipse) to read the contents of the excel file and storing it in a list of row objects. To read the file I have specified the file path in the code. In this case it is something like D:/Refreshed_data_daily/all_hue_posts_in_excel.xlsx.
What if the code is present in some other location i.e in some other system, the path need not be same. How do I handle such situation?

public class FacebookDataList{

```
private static final String FILE_NAME="D:/Refreshed_data_daily/all_hue_posts_in_excel.xlsx";
private static final String SHEET_NAME="nextv54plus_actions";
XSSFWorkbook workbook;

public static void main(String[] args){

    FacebookDataList obj= new FacebookDataList();
    List<FacebookFields> displayList= new ArrayList<FacebookFields>();
    displayList=obj.getTheDataIntoList();
    System.out.println("The Size of the list is:"+ displayList.size());
}

public List<FacebookFields> getTheDataIntoList() {
    List<FacebookFields> fbList= new ArrayList<FacebookFields>();
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fin= new FileInputStream(FILE_NAME);
        workbook= new XSSFWorkbook(fin);
        int sheetIndex=0;
        for (Sheet sheet : workbook) {
            readSheet(sheet,sheetIndex ++, fbList);}

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fbList;
}

private void readSheet(Sheet sheet, int sheetIndex , List<FacebookFields> fbList) {

    if(SHEET_NAME.equals(sheet.getSheetName())){
        workbook.removeSheetAt(sheetIndex);
        return;
    }
    for (Row row : sheet){
        if (row.getRowNum() > 0)
            fbList.add(readRow(row));}

}

private FacebookFields readRow(Row row) {

    FacebookFields record= new FacebookFields();
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        switch (cell.getColumnIndex()) {
        case 0: record.setName(cell.getStringCellValue()); 
        break; 
        case 1: record.setId(cell.getStringCellValue()); 
        break; 
        case 2: record.setDate(cell.getStringCellValue());
        break; 
        case 3: record.setMessage(cell.getStringCellValue());
        break; 
        case 4: record.setType(cell.getStringCellValue());
        break; 
        case 5: record.setPage(cell.getStringCellValue());
        break; 
        case 6: record.setLikeCount(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
        break; 
        case 7: record.setCommentCount(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue())); 
        break; 
        case 8: record.setShareCount(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue())); 
        break; 
        }
    }

    return record;
}

public boolean checkIfListContainsData() {

    List<FacebookFields> checkList= getTheDataIntoList();   
    return !checkList.isEmpty() ;
}
```

}

Comment: Mention your queries properly. What kind of application either standalone or web application?  Is that file location will change dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

You could have the user input the location from the start.  Or, have it reach out to the location it should be and return an error to the user if the file is not present.

Comment: Even i had the same option of taking the input from the user. But I dont know how do i do it. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Add it to a config file. I've written the following class for config file object. Configuration should be inside a file called config.properties in the run path.

https://github.com/achinthagunasekara/JavaConfigFileReader

Something like this works well for storing application configuration.

Config File

```
ConfigItem1=ItemValue1
.
.
.
ConfigItemN=ItemValueN
```

Java Class

```
package Config;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 *
 * @author Achintha Gunasekara
 * @date 07.09.2015
 */

public class ConfigFileReader {

    //Configuration file used by the config reader
    //config file must be located inside the application path
    private final String file = "config.properties";
    private Properties properties;
    private static ConfigFileReader instance;

    public static ConfigFileReader getConfigFileReaderInstance() throws IOException {

        //there can only be once instance of the config reader
        if(instance == null) {

            instance = new ConfigFileReader();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private ConfigFileReader() throws IOException {

        loadConfig(file);
    }

    //read and load the config file
    private void loadConfig(String configFile) throws IOException {

        properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(configFile));
    }

    //reloads the configuration during runtime
    public void reloadConfig() throws IOException {

        loadConfig(file);
    }

    //reloads the configuration during runtime from a provided configuration file
    public void reloadConfig(String configFile) throws IOException {

        loadConfig(configFile);
    }

    //get the propery value for strng s
    public String getPropertyFor(String configItem) throws Exception {

        String value = properties.getProperty(configItem);

        if(value == null) {

            throw new Exception(configItem + " not found!");
        }

        return value;
    }
    //returns int property
    public Integer getIntPropertyFor(String configItem) throws Exception {

        return Integer.parseInt(getPropertyFor(configItem));
    }

    //returns double property
    public Double getDoublePropertyFor(String configItem) throws Exception {

        return Double.parseDouble(getPropertyFor(configItem));
    }

    //returns bool property
    public Boolean getBooleanPropertyFor(String s) throws Exception {

        return Boolean.parseBoolean(getPropertyFor(s));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of adding the path name to config.properties? I don't get it! Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

String array args defined here

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

contains command line arguments passed when executing the class or can be passed in eclipse run configuration.

change function to

```
public List<FacebookFields> getTheDataIntoList(String filePath)
```

and use filePath when initializing file input stream